# C++ declare an array based on a non-constant variable?

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic

```
void method(string a) {
  int n = a.size();
  int array[n];
}
```

The above code can compile correctly using gcc. How can the size of the array come from a non-constant variable? Does the compiler automatically translate the `int array[n]` to `int* array = new int[n]`?

Comment: It's a compiler extension.

Comment: Use `const`. Use reference. Use vector

Comment: With GCC, compile your code with `-pedantic-errors`, and then see what it says!

Comment: @Nawaz: Then compile with `-std=c++1y` and see what it says.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Hehe....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can the size of the array come from a non-constant variable?

Currently, because that compiler has a non-standard extension which allows you to use C's variable length arrays in C++ programs.

> Does the compiler automatically translate the `int array[n]` to `int* array = new int[n]`?

That's an implementation detail. I believe GCC places it on the stack, like normal automatic variables. It may or may not use dynamic allocation if the size is too large for the stack; I don't know myself.

Answer (score 3):

dynamic allocation. The `new` keyword will do this with a pointer and some allocation.

```
int * ptr;
int n = a.size();
ptr = new int[n];
```

Comment: another benefit of this is that the pointer address can be returned from a function, where a statically created array is wiped off the stack when the function returns

Comment: That variable ptr can be used just like an array, e.g. you can use the [] subscript like `ptr[a-1]` to access the last element of the array

Comment: I'd argue that a *disadvantage* of this is that you need to explicitly manage the memory yourself and remember to call `delete[]` later.  Really, just use a `std::vector`.

Comment: I suggest using the edit button below your answer. However, using `new` is not commonly desired in C++.

Comment: why so @chris ? And what is used instead?

Comment: @JacobMinshall, Because managing your own memory adds unneeded complexity to your application. You might say it's simple to free your memory every time you use it, but if it's in a class, you need extra member functions, and throw in some exceptions and you've got lots of extra code. Instead, use the proper RAII container, such as a `std::vector` or a smart pointer.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html) the compiler allows this expression in C++ as far as C90/99.